# Change spaces to -

Tags: php, mysql, format

I am inserting Alias field for my db called $alias
how do I code (I am using php for mysql insert)
to remove all spaces and replace space with "-" (trying to change it to "weburl format" ie removing spaces)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the method I use to santize strings for SEF urls:

```
    $slug = trim(strtolower($value));
    $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $slug);
    return preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $slug);
```

Feel free to add additional allowed characters to the first regex.

Please note that this is NOT Unicode or even full ISO-8891 safe, well, it is, but it'll drop anything that isn't `a-z`. That is, you may need to normalize the string beforehand (i.e., replace accented characters with their closes ASCII equivalent.) There's a number of SO questions and answers dealing with this that I've seen before, but I can't find them at the moment. I'll edit them in here if I stumble upon any.

Comment: Note that - needs to be the last character before the ] in the second line, so if you add more characters, add them before the -

Answer (score 0):

For just removing spaces, you want the [str_replace method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). However, when working with URLs, you might want to consider the [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) methods as well.